# Inserting longer numbers in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Which data type is suitable to insert larger numbers in SQLite. Can anybody please guide me? I want to insert numbers greater than 10 digits.

Comment: What kind of numbers? Integers? Or Decimals? How big can they be?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum `INTEGER` sqlite can store as a signed `BIGINT` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (9 and a bit [Quintillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)), which is "greater than 10 digits".

[SQLite Datatype Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

The [SQLite FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) also covers an import aspect of dealing with data in SQLite - the fact it uses [Dynamic Typing](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).